# No java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for com.google.common.base.Function

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error although I have added all the the libraries and dependencies as jar files.

```
Error shows like this : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at chrome_browsertest.main(chrome_browsertest.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

Comment: webdriver driver=new chrome driver(); then place system.setproperty ur problem get solved

Comment: Still not working ...!  . Help me out from this !

Comment: I think issue is that its not able to find chrome exe file path. can you put chrome drive exe at diff path, keep it in your project folder or keep it at C:\anyfolder and then give that path accordingly.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X EI Capitan . Ok let's try one more time .

Answer (score 1):

**NoClassDefFoundError** will come if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.

The issue might have came because of path mismatching. Download the chrome driver in appropriate place and and give small path and try once.Example

```
 "E:\\Library\\chromedriver.exe"
```

We can call the browser driver in two ways.

1. Set up Environment Variable: By giving path in environment set-up we can access the the anything in in windows.So add the chrome driver path here. Then you can access the chrome like this:

   ```
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//same as firefox driver
   ```
2. `System.setProperty`: By using this we are giving driver path in script itself. Download chromedriver.exe and put this in appropriate driver. We put in E:/ drive for our example.

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   public class ChromeDriver1 {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.get("http://google.com");
       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when JRE cant find a class. Double check you have included all the necessary libraries

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, this Exception is thrown when JRE can't find a class.This problem arises when we don't include a particular jar file i.e: `org-apache-commons-logging.jar` in the Referenced Libraries. Try downloading the jar and add it in the library. Hope your problem get solved.